# Class is added but animated element property is not changed

Tags: javascript, css, background-color, css-animations

An element is infinitely background color changing (gradient).
When I add a class that is supposed to : 
- pause the animation
- change border
- change background color

pausing is ok, new border is ok, but background color stays to the one reached at the moment of the animation pausing.

It seems that I'm missing something... If someone could help me I will be pleased.

If useful, here is a short version of the problem :

http://jsfiddle.net/iwonder/gxbWf/

Please, be clement, I learn by doing (and reading of course...)

```
<div id="container"><div id="spot" class="grad2 looping2"></div>
    <div id="spot" class="grad2"></div>
</div>
<input id="test" type="button" value="click" onclick="stop()"/>


.grad2 {
    float:left;
    width:25px;
    height:25px;
    border-radius:25px;
    background: yellow;
    border:2px solid purple;}

.looping2{
    -webkit-animation-duration:2s;
    -webkit-animation-name: twostates2;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;  
    -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
}

.purple {
    -webkit-animation-play-state:paused;
    background:purple;
    border:2px solid green;

}
@-webkit-keyframes twostates2{    
  0%    {background: yellow}
  20%   {background: red}
  40% {background: yellow}
  60%   {background: red}
  81% {background: yellow}
  84%   {background: red}
  87% {background: yellow}
  90% {background: red}
  93% {background: yellow}
  97%   {background: red}
  100% {background: yellow}
}



function stop() {

document.getElementById('spot').className += ' purple'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by fiddling (before posting, I tried other ways that didn't work):

1. instead, I 1st turned animation to only 1 iteration :
   `.stop {
   -webkit-animation: whateverName 4s 1;
   /* applies to EVERY running animation */
   }`
2. then : turned border and background to the wanted values with a transition :
   `.purpletrans {
   background:purple;
   border:2px solid green;
   transition: background 1s linear, border 5s ease;}`
   Maybe it's an obvious solution, but it was not for me. Any other answer would still be appreciated. If ever...
   Thanks for reading
    Updated jsfiddle with new working way, if it could helps a newbie... http://jsfiddle.net/iwonder/gxbWf/